# Rank values based on individual users

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like the follow:

```
User              Area        
Sarah             123.4
Sarah             20.5
Sarah             43
Sam               86
Sam               101
Sam               32.6
Justin            45
Justin            125.8
Justin            39
Justin            88.4
Zac               21
Zac               4
Zac               111
```

I want to sort the greatest area to smallest, however I want separate top areas for each individual user.

I have tried: test$Ranking1 <- order(test$User, test$Area, decreasing = FALSE ), but this ranks them all together
I then tried: test$Ranking1 <- ave(test$User, test$Area, FUN= rank ), and while others seem to have said this will work my output/ results give the middle (average) value a ranking of 1 and then going up by which is closest to the average. I was 1 to be the largest area not the average.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like `test[do.call(order, test), ]`? What do you mean "I want to separate top areas for each individual user"?

Comment: If you use, `test$Ranking2 <- ave(test$Area, test$User, FUN= rank )` (note that I switched the order of the arguments in `ave`) it will rank the `Area` for each `User` from 1 (lowest) up to the max (for the sample data it is 3)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)                 # Load package
setDT(dat)                          # convert to data.table
dat[,max(Area),by=User]             # compute

dat[,sort(Area),by=User]                     # Sort increasing
dat[,sort(Area,decreasing = T),by=User]      # Sort decreasing
```

Hope this helps!
Read the documentation of the package, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to rank `area` within each individual, and also want to know the largest area for each individual:

```
## make up data
set.seed(1)
user <- rep(LETTERS[sample(26, 5)], each=sample(5, 1))
area <- rnorm(length(user), 100, 20)
d <- data.frame(user, area)

library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(user) %>%
  mutate(ranking=rank(-area), top_area=max(area)) %>%
  ungroup()

   user      area ranking top_area
1     G 131.90562       1 131.9056
2     G 106.59016       4 131.9056
3     G  83.59063       5 131.9056
4     G 109.74858       3 131.9056
5     G 114.76649       2 131.9056
6     J 111.51563       2 130.2356
7     J  93.89223       4 130.2356
8     J 130.23562       1 130.2356
9     J 107.79686       3 130.2356
10    J  87.57519       5 130.2356
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your desired output? If you want the order reversed, wrap a `rev()` around the `rank()` function.

```
x = "User              Area        
     Sarah             123.4
     Sarah             20.5
     Sarah             43
     Sam               86
     Sam               101
     Sam               32.6
     Justin            45
     Justin            125.8
     Justin            39
     Justin            88.4
     Zac               21
     Zac               4
     Zac               111"

rank.foo = function(x) {
  z = numeric()
  for (i in as.character(unique(x$User)))
  {z = c(z, rank(subset(x, User == i)$Area))}
  return(z)
}

cbind(df, rank.foo(df))

     User  Area rank.foo(df)
    Sarah 123.4            3
    Sarah  20.5            1
    Sarah  43.0            2
      Sam  86.0            2
      Sam 101.0            3
      Sam  32.6            1
   Justin  45.0            2
   Justin 125.8            4
   Justin  39.0            1
   Justin  88.4            3
      Zac  21.0            2
      Zac   4.0            1
      Zac 111.0            3
```